# Sum of Unit Fractions Equal to 1 Has Finitely Many Solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, fractions

My book on abstract algebra had a small puzzle in it I was interested in. 
It asks the reader to prove that

> $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{x_j} = 1$ only has finitely many solutions where $x_j \in \mathbb{N}$.

My first attempt to proof it was with induction. It's easy to see that for $n=1$ it only has $1$ solution. For the induction step I assume that in the case $n=k+1$ we have infinitely many solutions, so it follows that $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{k}\frac{1}{x_j} = \frac{x_k-1}{x_k}$ which implies that $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{k}\frac{1}{x_j} = \frac{1}{x_k}$ (assuming $x_k \neq 1$).

This is pretty much as far as I got. I'd really love to have a hint rather than a full solution if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: First order the $x_i$ according to size. Then try all possibilities for $x_1$, then $x_2$, etc. The constraints that $x_i\ge x_{i-1}$ and that $\frac{n-i+1}{x_i}\ge 1-\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}x_j$ mean that one only has to try finitely many possibilities for $x_i$ at each step.

Comment: How does this provide a bound on n being finite? If n can be arbitrarily large, then it does not suffice to only show that each xi has finitely many possibilities.

Comment: It shows that for every given $n$ with $1=\frac{1}{x_1}+\ldots +\frac{1}{x_n}$ there are $f(n)<\infty$ solutions. We have $x_1\ge x_2\ge \cdots \ge x_n$. of course, for $n\to \infty$ also $f(n)\to \infty$.

Comment: Ah, I thought the question was about arbitrary n with a trivial-solutions-avoiding condition on the xi's. (If the xi's must be distinct, and n is not fixed, are there finitely or infinitely many solutions?)